# QGraphicsView::centerOn(...) плохо работает

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Всем привет!

хочу чтобы при масштабировании центр сцены оставался в центре, 
делаем такие действия:

```
//масштабируем так чтобы центр сцены оставался в центре
//определяем точку центра viewporta
QPoint Center(0.5 * this->width(), 0.5 * this->height());
//переводим в масштаб сцены
QPointF SCenter = mapToScene(Center);
//определяем точку по объекту PixMapItem
SCenter = GrapthPixMapItem.mapFromScene(SCenter);

//масштабируем объект 
GrapthPixMapItem.setScale(1.20);
//отображаем всю сцену 
this->setSceneRect(MainGraphicsScene.itemsBoundingRect());

//получаем координаты центра масштабирования в масштабе сцены
SCenter = GrapthPixMapItem.mapToScene(SCenter);
```

теперь казалось осталось осталось сделать

```
this->ceneterOn(SCenter);
```

и все будет хорошо. Ан нет, центр при таком действии уплывает. В хелпе написано что скролбары int, а центр float и вроде как может быть неточно. Однако если продолжить вместо this->ceneterOn(SCenter) продолжить код так:

```
//получаем координаты цетра масштабирования в масштабе viewport 
Center = mapFromScene(SCenter);

//считаем дельту сдвига
Center.setX(Center.x() - 0.5 * this->width());
Center.setY(Center.y() - 0.5 * this->height());

//сдвигаем скролбары так чтобы точка масштабирования стала в центре 
this->horizontalScrollBar()->setValue(this->horizontalScrollBar()->value() + Center.x());
this->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(this->verticalScrollBar()->value() + Center.y());
```

Центр стоит достаточно хорошо и плавает совсем чуть чуть между шагами масштабирования, вокруг одной точки. Я что-то не так делают с centerOn. Или это такая судьба и надо просто делать все руками?

---

Видать я все-таки что-то не понимаю... Если задать resizeAnchor в центр viewport и покрутить масштаб, все опять происходит вокруг некого центра, который совпадает с тем центром что давал centerOn(), но не совпадает с реальным центром viewport. Что я делаю не так?

---

Ну все оказалось просто, точки масштабирования задаются естественно для сцены, а не объектов. И работая по ним надо работать с масштабом сцены. Важным моментом является задавать не только resizeAnchor, но и TransformationAnchor. Тогда задав центр через centerOn(...) и изменяя масштаб сцены, выбранная точка выходит в центр сцены если может, и остается видна если сцену подвинуть нельзя. Все работает правильно

Comment: Не очень понятно, Вы масштабируете сам элемент для чего? Масштабируете мышью (колесом)? Может лучше непосредственно представление (view) сцены масштабировать?

Comment: масштабирую по всякому и колесом, и ползунком, и кнопками. Может быть лучше и вью сцены, я пока не думал про такую магию. Пошел прямым путем, мне надо было чтобы объект стал побольше, я его и увеличил.... Но вроде я понял в чем дело, все эти анкоры и прочее это про сцену, а не про объекты, последние живут в своем пространстве...

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте как-нибудь так:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <QtGui/QWheelEvent>
#include <QtWidgets/QGraphicsView>

class GraphicsView : public QGraphicsView {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit AGraphicsView(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR) {
            setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView::AnchorViewCenter);
            setScene(new QGraphicsScene(this));
        }

        virtual ~AGraphicsView() {}

    protected:
        virtual void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event) {
            const qreal factor
                = std::pow(1.2,event->angleDelta().y()/240.0);

            scale(factor, factor);
        }

};
```

Comment: Да, спасибо.  Я уже переписал на масштаб через сцену. Стало понятно как работает centerOn() и как работает масштаб относительно центра. Сначала руками написал примерно тоже самое, а оно оказывается само все может:)... Осталось непонятно с ресайзом по курсору. На малых масштабах оно работает хорошо, но потом его начинает дико дергать, так что точка улетает. Какие условия работы по курсору?

Comment: "С ресайзом по курсору" - это, в смысле, выделение или колесо мыши?

Comment: когда колесом крутишь масштаб, а анкором выбран UnderMouse. Там при увеличении сцены очень дергает точку на которую указываешь. То есть на малых масштабах все работает как хочется, увеличивается вокруг точки на которую указывает курсор, а дальше после 1000% уже начинает колбасить, иногда даже точка улетает с экрана. Думаю это уже какие-то проблемы округления, слишком масштаб большой...

Comment: Вероятно фактор масштабирования должен изменяться в зависимости от, собственно, масштаба. То есть, если увеличиваем, то делаем это с меньшим `factor`. Наверное так. К сожалению, не пробовал.